# Finding the data in a XML file using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML and I need to find some data from that using xslt,Here is the XML

```
<root>

  <product>
    <id>134021</id>
    <bulkdiscountpricelist ></bulkdiscountpricelist>
    <webout extra="webout">1</webout>
  </product>

  <product>
    <id>134022</id>
    <bulkdiscountpricelist ></bulkdiscountpricelist>
    <webout extra="webout">0</webout>
  </product>

  <product>
    <id>134023</id>
    <bulkdiscountpricelist ></bulkdiscountpricelist>
    <webout extra="webout">1</webout>
  </product>


  <product>
    <id>134023</id>
    <bulkdiscountpricelist ></bulkdiscountpricelist>
    <webout extra="webout">0</webout>
  </product>

</root>
```

I want to check each `id` that has `webout`=1 using XSLT.

I  tried a code but it is not working. My code is like

```
<xsl:value-of select="$result//product/id"/>
```

Comment: We can't answer this without more code. What is `$result` ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need write a template like this

```
<xsl:template match="product[webout=1]">
```

to process all the relevant `product` elements.

We can't really help you more unless you describe what you are doing better. Where has your variable `$result` come from? You can't examine the contents of a variable like that unless you have the `set-node` extension in your XSLT transformer.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it by `for-each` like

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/product[./webout=1]">
     <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something like `$result//product[webout=1]/id` in xslt "1.1" otherwise use node-set() extension function to get output.